# how to get specific records

Tags: php, sql

i'm making a simple site for movies and i wanna display related movies in the page..
the problem that my database contains American and Indian movies in movies table
i'm trying to find a way that when the visitor click on any american movie the related movies would appear only the american movies (there is a column called "movie_lang" in my table that labels the american movies as number 1 and the indian as number 2)
this's as far as i can get

```
 $query=mysql_query("select * from movies order by id desc limit 4");
      while($m=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($m['movie_lang']== '1'){
            echo '<a href="view_movie.php?id='.$m['id'].'"><img src="uploads/poster/'.$m['thumbnail'].'" title="'.$m['name'].'"></a>' ;}
    else{

          echo '<div class="hidden"></div>"';
    }

      }
```

not sure of my code. sorry...new to this...

Comment: Why not use "select * from movies where movie_lang = 1 order by id desc limit 4"? Also, is this code giving you an error? If so, please post that.

Comment: cannot do that because this will only display the movies that are labeled as 1 ( american movies)  and the code worked find ,not sure what to do next, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna display only the american movies because the visitor click on it, you can show all the american movies using your query database.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from movies where movie_lang = 1 order by id desc limit 4");
```

If you want the indian movies, just change the parameter in movie_lang to 2. This parameter can be for you a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I understand the issue, let me know if I missed it though: You want to list all types of movies, but if a user clicks a link for an american movie, you want to show him only american language movies on later pages. Here's my idea:

```
// When a page loads, it checks if the 'selected_lang' variable is set. If so, it creates a language filter
$previous_lang = isset($_GET['selected_lang'] && is_numeric($_GET['selected_lang'])) ? " where movie_lang = " . $_GET['selected_lang'] . " " : "";

// We assemble queries which will use a language filter if we have one, or all languages if not
$query=mysql_query("select * from movies $previous_lang order by id desc limit 4");

while($m=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if($m['movie_lang']== '1'){
        // We include a 'selected_lang' variable in our link, so that page now nows the language of the movie the user picked
        echo '<a href="view_movie.php?selected_lang=1&id='.$m['id'].'"><img src="uploads/poster/'.$m['thumbnail'].'" title="'.$m['name'].'"></a>' ;
    } else {
        echo '<div class="hidden"></div>"';
    }
}
```

This code looks to see if a 'selected_lang' was set, and if so, uses it for subsequent SQL queries. You may have to chop bits here and there for different pages, and possibly re-arrange it if you want to write your own (sensible) where clauses.

Let me know if you need more help with this.